# How to make Spring Security resolve Eureka names?

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I have an OAuth 2.0 Resource Server and I want to configure the issuer URI:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://AUTHORIZATION-SERVICE/auth/realms/books
```

All services are registered with eureka

```yaml
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://<ip>:8761/eureka
```

And the `@EnableEurekaClient` annotation is set.

But when I start the service I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtDecoderByIssuerUri' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/servlet/OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration$JwtDecoderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder]: Factory method 'jwtDecoderByIssuerUri' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://AUTHORIZATION-SERVICE/auth/realms/books"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at de.fronetic.books.room.Application.main(Application.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder]: Factory method 'jwtDecoderByIssuerUri' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://AUTHORIZATION-SERVICE/auth/realms/books"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://AUTHORIZATION-SERVICE/auth/realms/books"
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getConfiguration(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:85) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getConfigurationForIssuerLocation(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:52) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(JwtDecoders.java:88) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration$JwtDecoderConfiguration.jwtDecoderByIssuerUri(OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration.java:93) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://AUTHORIZATION-SERVICE/auth/realms/books/.well-known/openid-configuration": AUTHORIZATION-SERVICE; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: AUTHORIZATION-SERVICE
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:748) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:651) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getConfiguration(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:72) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: AUTHORIZATION-SERVICE
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:229) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:608) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:557) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1253) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:739) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I use the IP instead of the eureka name everything works fine.
How can I make Spring Security to resolve the Eureka names?

**EDIT**

As requested my security config:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/rooms/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_read")
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/rooms").hasAuthority("SCOPE_write")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
    }
}
```

Dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Boot Dependencies Start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Boot Dependencies End -->
    <!-- Spring Cloud Dependencies Start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Cloud Dependencies End -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: can you share your spring security config java file?

Comment: Also ensure your issuer url is not blocked by any firewall

Comment: Hi, I added the security config and also ensured that the url is not blocked by any firewall

Comment: Try adding @@EnableResourceServer to the security config class and check once.

Comment: I do not have this annotation on my classpath. I use this dependency: `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`